# How to get value/contents of TextBox and use it as filename for an image captured by webcam?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

I wrote a code in Visual Basic (via Visual Studio) that captures a still photo from a webcam using the ClipBoard and SaveFileDialog, and I want it to automatically get the TextBox1.Text as its filename. I really have no idea how to do it. Here is the code so far:

```
data = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
    If data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
        bmap = CType(data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Image)
        picCapture.Image = bmap
        picCapture.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        ClosePreviewWindow()


        If sfdImage.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End If
    End If
```

And also, can I make it to save the file in the background using the same parameters without bothering to include the SaveFileDialog into the equation?  Thank you for  your answers.

Comment: So the `TextBox` contains only the name of the file or the full path of the image???

Comment: @MousaAlfhaily yes, the textbox only contains the filename. THank you in advance.

Comment: In this case, you don't have to use the `SaveFileDialog`, you have to use instead the `FolderBrowserDialog` because you want to take the name of the file form a `TextBox` in the form, and the `SaveFileDialog` forces the user to choose the name within the dialog it-self, so it will not fits you needs in your case.